# The type [classname] must implement the inherited abstract method KeyListener.keyTyped(KeyEvent)

Tags: java, keylistener

java: I'm stuck on the error **The type Pong.Move1 must implement the inherited abstract method 
 KeyListener.keyTyped(KeyEvent)** when I used keyListener. I don't get what it means? Help?

Here's the Thread I'm having trouble on...

```
private class Move1 extends Thread implements KeyListener{
  public void run(){
    addKeyListener(this);
    while(true){
      //hitRight makes you lose.
      //point is how many times it ricochets.
      if(ball.intersects(borderRight)){
        hitRight = true;
      }
      if(ball.intersects(borderLeft)){
        point++;
      }
  }

}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event){
while(event.getKeyCode()==40||event.getKeyCode()=='s'){
direction = DOWN;
Thread.sleep(500);
}
}
public void KeyReleased(KeyEvent event){

}
public void KeyTyped(KeyEvent event){

}

}
```

I'm also stuck on the `Thread.sleep(500);` line I have. It says **Unhandled exception type InterruptedException**. Any help? Thx.

Oh, I forgot something.
1:When I try to run it, the **only** error I get is:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at Pong.main(Pong.java:50)`. That's the `public static void main(String[] args)` line. My complete code is at the end so you can look at it (plz)
2:I'm using eclipse.
3:I am basically a beginner (not really)

My complete code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;
public class Pong extends JFrame{
    public final int WIDTH = 1000, HEIGHT = 1000;
    final int UP = 1, DOWN = 2;
    boolean hitRight;
    int point = 0;
    int direction;
    Rectangle bg = new Rectangle(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    Rectangle borderLeft = new Rectangle(0,0,WIDTH/320,HEIGHT);
    Rectangle borderRight = new Rectangle(WIDTH-WIDTH/320,0,WIDTH/320,HEIGHT);
    Rectangle borderTop = new Rectangle(borderLeft.x,borderLeft.y,WIDTH,HEIGHT/35);
    Rectangle borderBottom = new Rectangle(0,HEIGHT-HEIGHT/320,WIDTH,HEIGHT/320);
    Rectangle ball = new Rectangle(WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2,WIDTH/64,HEIGHT/64);
    Rectangle board = new Rectangle(WIDTH-WIDTH/160,0,WIDTH/128,HEIGHT/10);
public void paint(Graphics graphics){
super.paint(graphics);
graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
graphics.fillRect(bg.x,bg.y,bg.width,bg.height);
graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
graphics.fillRect(borderLeft.x, borderLeft.y, borderLeft.width, borderLeft.height);
graphics.fillRect(borderRight.x, borderRight.y, borderRight.width, borderRight.height);
graphics.fillRect(borderTop.x, borderTop.y, borderTop.width, borderTop.height);
graphics.fillRect(borderBottom.x, borderBottom.y, borderBottom.width, borderBottom.height);
graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
graphics.fillRect(ball.x,ball.y,ball.width,ball.height);
graphics.fillRect(board.x,board.y,board.width,board.height);
}
    /**
     * This Pong game made by me.
     * This has no copied code.
     * Any similarities are coincidences.
     * @param args
     */
    /*
     * The constructor.
     */
    public Pong(){
    super("Pong");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Pong p = new Pong();
    }
    /*
     * The move thread.
     */
private class Move1 extends Thread implements KeyListener{
    public void run(){
        addKeyListener(this);
            while(true){
        //hitRight makes you lose.
        //point is how many times it ricochets.
    if(ball.intersects(borderRight)){
        hitRight = true;
    }
    if(ball.intersects(borderLeft)){
        point++;
    }
                    }

        }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event){
    while(event.getKeyCode()==40||event.getKeyCode()=='s'){
    direction = DOWN;
    Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    }
    public void KeyReleased(KeyEvent event){

    }
    public void KeyTyped(KeyEvent event){

    }

    }
}
/*
 * End of move thread...
 */
```

Comment: Which is the question? the first one or the second one?

Comment: Why would you expect the code to run when it had an error during compilation?

Comment: I didn't say I expected it to run. I said that when I TRIED to run it I got an error and I ALSO asked what the errors were. That's it.

Comment: But still, what's the compilation error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to implement KeyListener, you need to implement all of the methods that that individual interface contains.
These are:

```
keyPressed
keyDown
keyTyped
```

In order to use interfaces you must implement all of their methods.

Also, Thread.sleep(500) might generate an exception. Java is basically requiring you to handle an error just in case something goes wrong. To do this, you need a try...catch, like so:

```
try
{
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
catch(InterruptedException e)
{
    System.out.println("Error!");
}
```

Comment: Okay I got it, it was the parentheses... fail.

Answer (score 2):

Your first error, related to KeyListener, is simply a case error.  In Java, methods and variables are named following [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), and the language is case-sensitive, so you must define your method as `keyTyped` instead of `KeyTyped`.  The same applies for `keyReleased`.

As for your second error, you must make changes necessary to handle the `InterruptedException` declared to be thrown by Thread#sleep.  You can surround that method call in a [try](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)-[catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) block. (However, note that the KeyEvent's keycode will never change, so you've got a potential infinite while loop there.)

I recommend reading [a tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) or two on implementing a key listener.

Comment: Would you by any chance know the compilation error's cause? Thanks by the way.

Comment: The compilation errors are caused by running a program which hasn't successfully compiled.

Comment: Okay, I think it was the parentheses, I fixed it, and thanks again.